# How to get the size of the installed package via MacPort?

Tags: macports

`port installed` displays all the installed packages on the local machine, but is there any way to list the size of each one? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a build in command from Macports to list the size of your installs, but you can do this:

Try this command in the terminal:

```
du -sh /opt/local/var/macports/software/*
```

This will give you the size of every package in /opt/local/var/macports/software/*, which I *believe* is the default install location.

Obviously, if you install your ports somewhere else you can use

```
 du -sh [directory]
```

Without a built in Macports command, this is the probably the best you can do.

One alternative that comes to mind is creating a script that would take the output of

```
 port installed
```

and echo the size of each install.

edit:

I was mistaken. /opt/local/var/macports/software/* contains the *tarbells* that the installations were extracted from, so the sizes will be smaller.

If you do du -sh /opt/local, it should list the size of everything, but there may be a few non-macports packages in the list.

The command `port contents installed` will show you the directory of everything macports has installed.

Comment: Slightly modified version to see items sorted by size: du -sk /opt/local/var/macports/software/*| sort -n

Answer (score 13):

```
port space --units MB installed
```

Nice and easy, has been available since [version 2.0](http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/branches/release_2_0/base/ChangeLog) all the way back in 2011!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small bash function that will take any valid macports query

```
function port_size {
    size=0
    pkg_size=0
    for pkg in $(port $@ | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1 }')
    do
        pkg_size=$(port contents $pkg \
            | sed -r 's/^[[:space:]]*(.*)[[:space:]]*$/\1/g;s/ /\\ /g' \
            | tail -n +2 | xargs du | cut -f1 | paste -sd '+' | bc)
        size=$(( $size + $pkg_size ))
        printf "%10d %s\n" $pkg_size $pkg
    done
    printf "%10d %s\n" $size "Total Size (KB)"
}
```

I've only tested it with GNU versions of sed and awk but it should work regardless.

```
port_size installed   # will print out all installed packages and their size

port_size installed gcc*    # will print out all packages matching gcc* wildcard
```

Again, any valid macports query will work (including `installed inactive` or `outdated`.

Comment: But OS X doesn't ship with GNU `sed`, and BSD `sed` doesn't support the `-r` option. Anyway, here's a one-liner which will tell you the size in KB of a single port (I use `guile` as an example): `port contents --size --units B guile | awk '{total += $1}; END{ printf("%0.2f KB\n", total/1024) }'`